# How to disable default title in react-data-grid

Tags: reactjs, react-data-grid

react-data-grid is having default tooltip to each cell. It adds the title attribute automatically. I don't want that tooltip, how can I hide it?

Also, I don't want to use [custom formatter](https://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/docs/examples/cell-formatting). I think it will be overhead.

e.g [Try to hover on any cell](https://codesandbox.io/s/62pnlx07nr)

See unwanted tooltip on Kristin here

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It might not be possible to get around without custom `formatter`

As far as overhead, check out the implementation it makes use of `SimpleCellFormatter`
https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/blob/master/packages/react-data-grid/src/formatters/SimpleCellFormatter.js there is nothing special going on there

```
class SimpleCellFormatter extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    value: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.number, PropTypes.object, PropTypes.bool])
  };

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    return nextProps.value !== this.props.value;
  }

  render() {
    return <div title={this.props.value}>{this.props.value}</div>;
  }
}
```

Have your custom formatter like this (same as above except the `title` attribute):

```
class CustomSimpleCellFormatter extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    value: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.number, PropTypes.object, PropTypes.bool])
  };

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    return nextProps.value !== this.props.value;
  }

  render() {
    return <div >{this.props.value}</div>;
  }
}
```

And it attached to your `columns`

```
const columns = [
  {
    key: "id",
    name: "ID",
    sortDescendingFirst: true
  },
  {
    key: "title",
    name: "Title",
    title: false
  },
  {
    key: "firstName",
    name: "First Name",
formatter: CustomSimpleCellFormatter,
  },
...
```

Hope that helps.